# If a sprite is entirely outside the view, will it still be rendered?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm just getting started with PixiJS. I am wondering if I should hide the sprite when they are out of view. This becomes wasteful if they are not rendered.[image]
If a sprite is entirely outside the view, will it still be rendered? Should I write a conditional statement to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should set `obj.visible = false;` to prevent rendering out-of-viewport objects for speed purposes.  Nothing will break if you don't, but it will chew up time rendering invisible pixels.  PixiJS doesn't do view frustrum culling by default, though I believe there are a few plugins that will help if you don't want to roll your own solution.